# What is the difference between UIImage(named:) and UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName:)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift3, ios10

Swift 3/iOS 10 added a new initializer on `UIImage`, `imageLiteralResourceName`:

```
extension UIImage {

    required public convenience init(imageLiteralResourceName name: String)
}
```

How does this differ from `public init?(named name: String)`?  I `named` is a failable initializer while `imageLiteralResourceName` will crash on an invalid image name.  Does `imageLiteralResourceName` trade safety for performance?  When should you use `imageLiteralResourceName` over `named`?

Comment: apple docs seem incomplete on [this subject](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1849766-init)

Comment: I haven't downloaded Xcode 8 yet, but my guess would be that `imageLiteralResourceName` is just syntactic sugar to for the new image literals (and you would never call it explicitly).

Comment: @Fonix looks like there's no difference, see [`UIKit.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/UIKit/UIKit.swift)

Comment: @MartinR found the implementation in the open-source version of Swift, looks like there's no difference.  If it were for the new image literals, why wouldn't Apple keep it private?

Comment: All the `XxxLiteralConvertible` protocols and the corresponding `init(xxxLiteral ...)` methods are public, but I have never seen a reason to use them explicitly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the [open-source implementation of UIKit](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/UIKit/UIKit.swift), there seems to be no difference:

```
extension UIImage : _ImageLiteralConvertible {
  private convenience init!(failableImageLiteral name: String) {
    self.init(named: name)
  }

  public required convenience init(imageLiteralResourceName name: String) {
    self.init(failableImageLiteral: name)
  }
}

public typealias _ImageLiteralType = UIImage
```

All it does is force-unwrap the result of `init(named:)`.

It seems like it's just an implementation of the `_ImageLiteralConvertible` protocol found in [`CompilerProtocols.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CompilerProtocols.swift) :

```
public protocol _ImageLiteralConvertible {
  init(imageLiteralResourceName path: String)
}
```

[AppKit](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/AppKit/AppKit.swift) also has a similar implementation:

```
extension NSImage : _ImageLiteralConvertible {
  private convenience init!(failableImageLiteral name: String) {
    self.init(named: name)
  }

  public required convenience init(imageLiteralResourceName name: String) {
    self.init(failableImageLiteral: name)
  }
}

public typealias _ImageLiteralType = NSImage
```

This might have to do with the new image literal functionality (`#imageLiteral`) added to Xcode 8 and should never be called directly.

Comment: Reference 1 (Open Source UIKit Repo) link is out of date. Did they revoke the source code, or move it? I found [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/UIKit) in the stdlib, but it's not the full implementation

Comment: I think that last sentence is probably spot on.